# Float required Error while using logarithm

Tags: python, math

Hi I'm getting TypeError and i just don't know why...

```
x=float(40)
base=float(10)
math.log(x, [base])

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
TypeError: a float is required
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`math.log(x, [base])` doesn't literally mean "put `base` in brackets". This is what the documentation uses to denote an optional argument.

Remove them and it'll work

```
math.log(x, base)
```

Also, you don't need to use the `float` builtin to declare floats. Just add on a decimal component to your number and it will become a float:

```
x = 40.0

math.log(x, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't realized that until now.